# Simple Select Query of 250K records takes 17 sec to run on SQl Server 2008 R2

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a simple table with 14 fields, all nvarchar, 11 are length 30, 1 length 12, 1 length 4, 1 length 2.  When I run Select query on the table to retrieve all records (250K) and fields it takes about 24 sec.  I figured with such a simple query it would be faster.  Is there any way to speed this up?
In the execution plan Table Scan, I/O cost is 5.36979, CPU Cost 0.275, Operator cost 5.6449, subtree cost 5.6449, row size 395b.  Adding a Cluster Index reduces it only by about 5 secs.
Please Help!

Comment: maybe your network is slow?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the read time is significant, not that the query is slow. You can tell because the I/O cost is almost the entire query cost. (The subtree cost includes the Operator cost, and the Operator cost includes the I/O cost. So it's being driven by I/O Cost. That's why indexing doesn't really help.)

This may be related to the speed of the drives on your server, the overall utilization of the SQL server that causes it to be slow, or as a comment above notes, it could be that there are network bandwidth issues.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the response. The query was run on the server so the cost isn't related network related and nothing else is on the server other than Sql Server.  Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: If you can re-think the logic for what you're doing, there may be easier ways to do it. (Why do you need to retrieve the full table? Can you perform whatever task you need differently?) 

Alternatively, depending on the server setup, (talk to your DBA) if you need this to run a lot, you could store a copy in tempdb, which may be cached better, or even upgrade to solid state drives.